# Parent to child communication without event

Tags: angular, components

I have string parameter in child component that I need to show in my parent component.
It should be done when the page is loading. So, not on click or any other event.

How do you manage to do this?

So far I didn't find any answer that would fit my solution.

Comment: Why without event? That's how a child communicates up to its parent.

Comment: You are looking to share a variable between two components. Move it into a service shared by both components.

Comment: It's simple example, I just want to show a title from child component in parent component on loading.

Comment: It seems that you can still do it with an Output, just emit in the ngOnInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ruling out communication via events, you have the following options:

1. Communicate via a shared service. This is a common strategy, no example required.
2. Pass an object from the parent to the child. If the child updates a property on the the object reference, the parent will also see that updated value (albeit without notifications).

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7h5xl

The principle:

Parent creates an object and passes it to the child

**parent.ts**

```
obj = { value: ''; };
```

**parent.html**

```
<child [obj]="obj"></child>
```

The child receives the object and updates a property on it.

**child.ts**

```
@Input() obj: { value: string };

someMethod(): void {
  // update obj, which both parent and child reference
  this.obj.value = 'CHILD';
}
```

End result: whenever the parent reads from the property, it will see the value that the child has set.

Edit:

As Michael D points out, I chose to pass an object through rather than a string because object *references* are passed around rather than literal values.

Comment: It should also be noted this approach will work only for objects and will not work for other types. Since objects are passed by reference and other types are passed by value.

Comment: Added note for clarity. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewChild` to access children data in the parent component.

Demo : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r8z5u8)

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  secretString: string = "Hi there!";
}
```

Child component :

Place your child component in the parent and tag it:

```
<hello #cmp></hello>
```

Use ViewChild to access the data inside you component

```
@ViewChild('cmp', {static: true}) hi;
```

```
<p>
  This is comming from your child: {{hi.secretString}}
</p>
```

Comment: You don't even need `@ViewChild`. You could refer to the child component with the template reference variable directly in the parent template (e.g. `{{cmp.secretString}}`).